# extract values from extrapolated graph in excel

Tags: excel, graph, charts, extrapolation

can someone let  me know how can I extract/read values from a graph in excel that I generated using couple of values that I had. I then extrapolated the graph to generate projection. Now I want to read all projected values from graph.
Will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply use the same equation as trendline to calculate the needed values. So the question is how to get the equation of trendline. This is answered multiple times already.

Comment: Will appreciate if you could post some code on what you have tried so far.